# How I can get logged in user's info like email id,name,city etc. in Facebook with uId

Tags: java, javascript, facebook

Can any one help me to  get logged in user's info like email id,name,city etc. with the help of  Facebook  uId .  " Long uid = apiClient.getLoggedInUser ();"
 Users_getInfo is not useful. It returns No of users connected to _User & according that there info gets.

If user login  successfully using fb connect, Facebook gives us uid.
However, I need to match the logged in user with our member's account
If that member is not present in DB then want to register him
and I'm trying to do that with e-mail(hashed) address and other info.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/ this function gives you some of the information of user. Like uid
first_name
middle_name
last_name
name
locale
current_location
affiliations (regional type only)
pic_square
profile_url
sex

Comment: Thanks for Replay. User.getInfo returns list of user with their info.
I want email id,name etc  when any user sign in through Facebook.

Comment: Means want's Facebook Logged in Users email id & other info.

Comment: Ok. this function gives you first - last name and proxified email.

Comment: Hello Osman.... 1 More Problem
In Facebook: How to get User's list_ of_friends_ ID when User is offline[not Sign In].

Comment: As you know,We are Integrating facebook application in our website.
Our website development in Java's GWT[Googlw Web Toolkit] FrameWork. We are refering "Gwittit" sample code
We open facebook account for our website and want to show all users[friends] photo conected to Website's FACEBOOK account when FB A/C is offline [not sign in].

We have used apiclient.getFriendList() in that we get list of all user id [with photo]connected to Our website's fb a/c.But Problem is that we have to sign in first and we don't want that
bcoz our website's fb a/c not everytime sign in

Comment: Hope for the Best Co-operation